# How do I answer a question which contains multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084904/alloy-ui-scheduler-language) contains two questions (and it references [an even better example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314655/alloyui-scheduler) which contains many questions). I only have the expertise to answer one of those questions. Should I answer this question? Should I just comment? What's the general consensus on how to answer questions like these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.

You vote or flag to close it as "too broad" or possibly "unclear what you are asking".

You can also add a comment asking the OP to split the question up, but answering is probably a bad idea as if the OP removes the bit you answered your answer becomes useless.